# Get Authorize.net settled transactions without querying getSettledBatchListRequest

Tags: authorize.net

My customer is switching to Authorize.Net. He performs about 400 transactions daily, where commissions are paid through an upline, but only ONCE A TRANSACTION is SETTLED.

For this purpose, I create an object that brings all unsettled transactions for the last 7 days, and query one by one:

```
let payload =
            {
                getTransactionDetailsRequest: {
                    merchantAuthentication: {
                        name: processor.name,
                        transactionKey: processor.key
                    },
                    transId: transaction.authorizeId
                }
            }
            const response = await axios.post(process.env.AUTHENDPOINT, (payload), { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });
```

I'm working on test mode, and querying 50 transactions takes forever; so this won't work.

I then switched to getSettledBatchListRequest, which brings a response similar to this one:

```
{
    "batchList": [
        {
            "batchId": "12329641",
            "settlementTimeUTC": "2021-12-16T00:18:04Z",
            "settlementTimeLocal": "2021-12-15T16:18:04",
            "settlementState": "settledSuccessfully",
            "paymentMethod": "eCheck"
        },
        {
            "batchId": "12332812",
            "settlementTimeUTC": "2021-12-16T02:26:14Z",
            "settlementTimeLocal": "2021-12-15T18:26:14",
            "settlementState": "settledSuccessfully",
            "paymentMethod": "creditCard",
            "marketType": "eCommerce",
            "product": "Card Not Present"
        },
        {
            "batchId": "12333336",
            "settlementTimeUTC": "2021-12-17T00:18:26Z",
            "settlementTimeLocal": "2021-12-16T16:18:26",
            "settlementState": "settledSuccessfully",
            "paymentMethod": "eCheck"
        },
```

The problem is that getSettledBatchListRequest forces me to a second query (getTransactionListRequest) for getting the transId by utilizing the batchId obtained through getSettledBatchListRequest.

The question is this: Is there a method to bring all settled transactions within a timeframe, which does not require batchId but a date range; or a different approach to accomplish what I need (mark a transaction as SETTLED on my end)?

Thanks.

Comment: What about getUnsettledTransactionListRequest so u get all unsettled transactions and assume the ones not present on the response are settled?

Comment: That would work perfectly if the only statuses would be "Settled" and "Unsettled"... the problem are the rest of the statuses, such as "VOID", "Under Review", etc. I cannot assume a missing unsettled transaction is a settled one because commissions are paid when a settlement takes place. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no way around. Authorize does not have an API for listing settled transactions together with the tranId. Ive no idea why they dont provide a simple API like that.

Im guessing y bring the last 7 days cause of eChecks, which make sense cause it takes up to 6 days to clear (usually just 3 but it tepends on the bank), the thing is that usually CC or DC transactions go thru just fine once they are accepted.

So if eChecks are the reason u are checking the transactions, a good scenario would be the one I said before, using getUnsettledTransactionListRequest and assuming a CC transaction as SETTLED on the fly; then keep using getTransactionDetailsRequest individually, but just for eChecks.

1. Call getUnsettledTransactionListRequest
2. If it is a card transaction and is not present at getUnsettledTransactionListRequest results, assume is settled and pay the commmissions.
3. If its a bank transaction and is not present at getUnsettledTransactionListRequest, then call getTransactionDetailsRequest for that specific eCheck transaction to find out the real status (FDS pending review, FDS failed review, Under Review, etc).

This will drastically decrease the number of calls to getTransactionDetailsRequest for each Unsettled transaction in your database.

Here're Authorize statuses:

https://account.authorize.net/help/Miscellaneous/Pop-up_Terms/ALL/Transaction_Status.htm

Comment: For the record, Unsettled transactions are successful transactions, they just were not sent to the bank yet. You are doin right by checking it on eChecks tough.

Comment: That worked for now. I am assuming "card" transactions as settled and then querying just "bank" transactions (one by one) which are only about 5% of the total transactions. It will work for now... but I will have to figure out a different solution for future recurring billings when they have thousands of bank transactions to process (and it will happen, this is an insurance carrier). You are right, authorize does not provide a solution to my problem (confirmed by their support team). Thanks and happy holidays.